# executing function on array using callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

What is the correct way to call the same function on an array of objects using callbacks to advance?

Essentially processing asynchronous calls sequentially.

```
doAsynchFunction(data,callback){
 console.log(data);
 wait(1000,callback); // do something that takes some time and execute callback
}
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

I'd like to see the numbers appear 1 second apart

Comment: Have you looked at myArray.map(myFunction)
?

Comment: Can you explain your problem statement in more details?

Comment: does the map() wait for the first function to complete before moving on to the next function?

Comment: @Daniel _"does the map() wait for the first function to complete before moving on to the next function?"_ Can you include array of functions at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Promise.all()` to process asynchronous processes where the result could be returned in any order

```js
var queue = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function asyncFn(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("processing:", n)
      resolve(n)
    }, Math.random() * 3000)
  })
}

Promise.all(queue.map(function(value) {
    return asyncFn(value)
}))
.then(function(results) {
    console.log(results)
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

or use a queue to process asynchronous functions in sequential order

```js
var queue = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
, res = []
, queueCopy = queue.slice(0);

function asyncFn(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("processing:", n)
      resolve(n)
    }, Math.random() * 3000)
  })
}

function processQueue(arr) {
  return asyncFn(arr.shift())
    .then(function(result) {
      res.push(result)
      if (arr.length) {
        return processQueue(arr)
      } else {
        return res
      }
    })
}

processQueue(queueCopy)
.then(function(results) {
    console.log(results)
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

---

Adjusting `js` at updated Question to utilizing `setTimeout()`, `Function.prototype.bind()` to pass function reference with parameters to `setTimeout`. Note, `callback` in this instance would be `doAsynchFunction` itself.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], aCopy = a.slice(0);

function wait(duration, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback()
  }, duration)
}

function doAsynchFunction(arr, cb) {
  console.log(arr.shift());
  // pass `arr`, and `cb` : `doAsynchFunction` to `wait`
  if (arr.length) wait(1000, cb.bind(null, arr, cb)); 
}

doAsynchFunction(aCopy, doAsynchFunction);
```

Comment: @Daniel See updated post

Comment: I think the wait might be confusing, the point is that the function is asynchronous and sequential, so the first function needs to be processed, which may take a second.  For a moment I thought this was more complicated then what I've got going, but I think that's just because you included the wait function to have working code.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I'm using right now

```
function run(onEnd){
    data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var proc = function(){
        if(i<data.length){
            dosomething(data[i],proc);
        }else{
            onEnd()
        }
        i++;
    }
    proc();
}
```