# "unexpected end of output" error on response.json()

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I keep getting an "unexpected end of output" error on response.json(). Am I way off base on what I am doing below?

```
Promise.all([requestOne, requestTwo])
  .then(responses => {
    responses.reduce((promise,response) => {
        return promise.then(() => {
             return response.json()
        }).then(result => result)
    }, Promise.resolve());
  })
```

Comment: What are `requestOne` and `requestTwo`? What is purpose of `.then(result => result)`?

Comment: `fetch` returns a `Promise` object; why do you use `.reduce()`, `Promise.resolve()`? Is response from server `JSON`?  Not certain what expected result is? Can you create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce issue?

Comment: requestOne and RequestTwo are requests that return json. I get the responses, then I have to parse to json. .json() returns anther promise which I need these to run in series. using reduce allows me to chain them. But the response.json() returns that error. https://esnextb.in/?gist=ad8d068078fc762c1434358357fdb0d3

Comment: The issue appears to be `{mode:"no-cors"}` setting at `fetch`. Try substituting `{method:"get"}` for `{mode:"no-cors"}` at `fetch` options, see http://plnkr.co/edit/ymKEeudclUp5ydSaijoP?p=preview

Comment: ha ha yeah, i responded with that on the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

The issue is `{mode:"no-cors"}` setting at `fetch`. Substitute `{method: "get"}` for `{mode:"no-cors"}` at `fetch` call

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ymKEeudclUp5ydSaijoP?p=preview

Comment: I will accept the answer but my solution did work also. Problem was that I am using no-cors, that must not play nice. I am not sure that map will keep the order correct? Too busy to look now.

Comment: If returning results in order is requirement, you can use `Array.prototype.shift()` without `Promise.all()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777616/executing-function-on-array-using-callbacks

Comment: @TonyVeigel Yes, your solution returned the result you were expecting.

Comment: I read about the method of doing it that way but I can't find the article. I will link to it if I come across it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TonyVeigel Updated post with solution for actual issue.